# Inserir DATA HORA no Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tenho o seguinte insert

```
    INSERT INTO tabela 
     (codigo, datahora ) 
     VALUES
     (1, NVL('',TO_DATE('19/07/2017 19:49:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')))
```

Por que [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2048.htm#OLADM624)?

Porque caso não tenha valor válido para data, ele inserir um valor vazio.

Mas caso tenha um valor válido para data, ele inserir o valor data/hora.

O problema:

Com o NVL, ele está salvando apenas a **data**, mesmo com o valor válido de **data/hora**, eu quero salvar a `data/hora`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução: colocar o **NVL** dentro do **TO_DATE**

```
    INSERT INTO tabela 
    (codigo, datahora ) 
    VALUES
    (1, TO_DATE(nvl('','19/07/2017 19:49:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

---

Justificativa: A função **NVL** irá ter um retorno do mesmo tipo do primeiro parâmetro, a não ser que ele seja null (nesse caso considera o tipo do segundo parâmetro). Assim, quando é enviada uma **string** vazia como primeiro parâmetro a função **NVL** terá um retorno do tipo **varchar**.

Por exemplo, execute a consulta abaixo que mostra o tipo de cada coluna da consulta:

```
    select 'Nulo' as tipo, dump(nvl(null,TO_DATE('19/07/2017 19:49:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))) from dual union
    select 'Vazio' as tipo, dump(nvl('',TO_DATE('19/07/2017 19:49:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))) from dual
```

Você verá que o retorno da função **NVL** quando com o 1º paramêtro **null** é do tipo **date** (Typ=13) e por isso nesse caso o insert daria certo. Entretanto, o retorno dessa mesma função passando a string vazia (como no seu exemplo) é do tipo **varchar** (Typ = 1). *

Assim, no caso do primeiro parâmetro ser a string vazia, o Oracle precisa converter os outros parametros para varchar pois ele precisa ter um retorno do mesmo tipo. Para essa conversão ele utiliza o formato de data que está definido na sessão no momento da execução do insert. Como esse formato geralmente não inclui a hora, a data é convertida para o formato de texto sem a hora. Para comprovar isso execute o comando abaixo antes do seu insert e a data será gravada no formato correto:

```
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

**Mais explicações sobre a função dump [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635). Tabela com os códigos referentes a cada tipo [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950).*